# How to use Leaflet.heat, mouse events/touch events, with mobile, like iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to use Mapbox/Leaflet to create a Heatmap. This is the exact example that I have working properly: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-heat/

The operative code is this:

```
map.on({
    movestart: function () { draw = false; },
    moveend:   function () { draw = true; },
    mousemove: function (e) {
        if (draw) {
            heat.addLatLng(e.latlng);
        }
    }
})
```

However, this does not work for **touch screens**. I have watched this video to get an idea of what I need to change: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwffqMAS8K8#t=100

Being new to JS and webapps in general, I am unsure of how to use the syntax explained at around 36:00 minutes into this video. He provides a function that forks mouse/touch handling differently according to what type of event is detected:

```
                var posX, posY;

                function positionHandler(e) {
                if ((e.clientX) && (e.clientY)) {
                    posX = e.clientX; posY = e.clientY;
                } else if (e.targetTouches) {
                    posX =  e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
                    posY = e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
```

I understand that here we define a function, positionHandler, to return the position of a mouse or touch event on the screen. But I do not know how to integrate this and make it work with the Leaflet syntax above.

**How do I adjust the example above for it to work on both desktops and touch screens?** Hopefully I have shown here that I've tried to do the research but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in the API for Leaflet. You should be able to use some of their event handlers in order to add this functionality. While I did not have luck just turning on the iHandler map.tap.enable(); I reconfigured it by replacing mouseend with click and mousemove with dblclick.

See documentation here for further information: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-interaction-handlers